# Add icons to videojs component with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, video.js

Recently I'm struggling with components of videojs.
I implement my Video Player with ReactJS Hooks and now I have to add some custom SVG icons.

But when I declare the new components of VideoJS I don't know how to add my custom icons and the documentation is very poor on this subject.

Here is my useEffect hook code that I initialized my VideoJS in:

```
useEffect(() => {
// Make sure Video.js player is only initialized once
if (!playerRef.current) {
  const videoElement = videoRef.current;

  if (!videoElement) return;
  let player = playerRef.current;

  player = videojs(videoElement, options, () => {
    videojs.log("player is ready");
    onReady && onReady(player);
  });

  console.log(player);

  let Button = videojs.getComponent("Button");

  let SettingsButton = videojs.extend(Button, {
    constructor: function (player, options) {
      console.log(player, options);
      Button.call(this, player, options);
      this.controlText("Settings");
    },
    handleClick: function () {
      console.log("Settings button clicked");
    },
    
  });

  videojs.registerComponent("SettingsButton", SettingsButton);
  player.getChild("ControlBar").addChild("SettingsButton", {}, 2);

}, [options, videoRef, onReady]);
```

Here is where I add new button-component where I want to add a settings-icon to:

```
let Button = videojs.getComponent("Button");

  let SettingsButton = videojs.extend(Button, {
    constructor: function (player, options) {
      console.log(player, options);
      Button.call(this, player, options);
      this.controlText("Settings");
    },
    handleClick: function () {
      console.log("Settings button clicked");
    },
    
  });

  videojs.registerComponent("SettingsButton", SettingsButton);
  player.getChild("ControlBar").addChild("SettingsButton", {}, 2);
```

I will appreciate it if anyone has a solution for this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have a solution for this problem.
For someone who might face with this problem, you can do like demonstrated below:

After you add the button (or component) of videojs you should apply a unique class to it:

```
let Button = videojs.getComponent("Button");

  let SettingsButton = videojs.extend(Button, {
    constructor: function (player, options) {
      Button.call(this, player, options);

      // ADD UNIQUE CLASS TO THE CUSTOM BUTTON
      this.addClass("vjs-setting-button");
    },
    handleClick: function () {
      console.log("Settings button clicked");
    },
  });

  videojs.registerComponent("SettingsButton", SettingsButton);

  player.getChild("ControlBar").addChild("SettingsButton", {}, 2);
```

Then in the css add a background-image to that class:

```
.vjs-setting-button {
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;

        // add background-image to class
        background-image: url('../assets/icons/Setting.svg'); 
        // Enter Your Own icon URL to use that
        
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```